# Getting the exception: "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" when calling SPUtility.GetPrincipalsInGroup()

Tags: 2010, claims-based-auth, claims

When calling the method:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.GetPrincipalsInGroup(SPWeb web, String input, Int32 maxCount, Boolean& reachedMaxCount)
```

I get the following stack trace:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the
>   current state of the object.
>        at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimsAuthRoleProvider.GetUsersInRole(SPWeb
>   web, String roleName, Int32 maxCount, Boolean& reachedMaxCount)
>        at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.GetPrincipalsInGroup(SPWeb
>   web, String input, Int32 maxCount, Boolean& reachedMaxCount)

This particular code is running remotely at a customer site, so I am unable to attach a debugger. This works locally and in staging outside of the customer's site. The local site, staging and the customer's production environment all use Claims-Based-Authentication and Windows Authentication.

Any ideas as to what could cause this exception?

Answer (score 0):

Add following entry in web.config of your site.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="5001" />
</appSettings>
```

This should resolve your issue.